# How to check HTTP status code in Apache configuration

Tags: apache, http

Is it possible to check Http status code in Apache configuration as `%{REQUEST_STATUS}` for instance?

Comment: What status code are you trying to check, and what would you do with it? A status code is part of a *response*, not a *request*, so it's generally determined too late to do much other than return it.

Comment: @IMSoP I wanna know when status code is 500 becouse I wan to apply basic authorization than. Only than, when status code is 200 i dont want to have basic authorization on my webside.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense; it's like saying "only ask the user's name if their name is Pete". I suspect there's some kind of [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313) here, and your actual requirement is somewhere else, but without more context it's hard to know how to help.

Comment: HTTP Status 500 means the application (host) crashed or had an unrecoverable error (the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request). Asking for authentication is the job of the application and not Apache. Checking for authorization is performed during the **request** phase and not the **response** phase.

Comment: @IMSoP    I use better_errors or web-console in case of an exception and I wanted to force basic auth for code 500 from applications in all cases. So as to maintain greater security.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "request status", and no way for a server to interact with a browser in the middle of serving an error message.

HTTP is not an interactive protocol; the browser sends a request, the server sends a response, and that's it. So if the browser sends a request, and the application crashes, the server can send a response with 500 and the error details, *or* a response with 401 requesting the user to log in. Either way, that's the end of the conversation.

When it receives a 401 response, the browser can't say "here's the login details, carry on with the current request", it has to make a *new* request. It can make an *identical* request, which *might* reproduce the error message; but the original error message is gone.

If the requirement is to show a different amount of detail to different users, you need some notion of *optional* authentication, so that the server can decide *immediately* whether to include the error details or not, without an extra round-trip to the browser. I would suggest either:

- Have a list of IP addresses which the application can check against; if the IP address of the request is in the list, include the error details.
- Have a custom login system where you can authenticate and set a "session cookie" in the browser. If the user has an active session cookie, include the error details.